# Hemoglobin level is not increasing in blood - Why?

Tags: blood, iron-supplements, hemoglobin

I have low level of hemoglobin in my blood. I include the followings in my food. Pomegranate,Iron syrups,Dates,Beetroot. Still my hemoglobin level is not increased properly. I want some suggestions to increase hemoglobin and the foods taken by me are enough or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iron supplements will only increase your hemoglobin levels if they are low because you lack iron. Ferritin levels are a better indicator of how much iron you have than hemoglobin. If this is the case, animal sources of iron are much more efficient than fruits and vegetables.